# Logistic regression with small and differing sample sizes

Tags: sas, statistics, logistic-regression, analysis

I am relatively new to statistics and confused about the best way to proceed with this logistic regression model (and if it is the correct statistical test to use).

I ran the model in SAS and I can't make sense of the results. My first question- does it matter that the groups are quite different in size AND the sample size is small? The total sample size excluding missing values is 57, with 13 in Group 3, 18 in Group 2, 26 in Group 1.

Second question- The odds ratios are very small, ranging from  <.0001 to 0.9 with a 95%CI of seemingly infinity. Is this just a function of the sample size?

Am I missing something here that would give more accurate results, or should a different test be utilized? It seems like as it stands it is not worth moving forward with the analysis.

The independent variable is social support-- continuous and ranging from 1.10 to 4 in 0.10 increments.
The outcome variable is sleep quality that has been combined into 3 separate groups -- categorical.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you doing ordinal logistic or multinomial logistic? Your group sizes are small, especially Group 2 (25+ is ideal) but if you have a single predictor it's not too bad. What do your bar charts look like?

Comment: @Reeza I believe I should be using multinomial logistic. The outcome is nominal/categorical so it would violate assumptions of ordinal, correct? My bar graph is relatively bell-shaped with the majority of data points at social support of 3. I would post a picture here if I could figure out how!

Comment: I'd suggest migrating this to CrossValidated or communities.sas.com. It's more pertaining to methodology not a technical coding question. I don't think there's anything you can do to correct for this, but there are limitations due to the size that you should be aware of for interpretation.

Comment: Sleep quality is ordinal but not on an equal scale most likely - kind of depends on how you measure it really.